# I need Help plotting the HH Bar and LL Bar on a Tradingview chart

Tags: pine-script, indicator, pine-script-v4

I am trying to create an indicator to plot swing points on the chart.

Basically after 3 bullish bars and 3 bearish bars I want the indicator to look back to the last 6 bars and plot a point figure on the highest bar to illustrate the Swing High and that after 3 bearish bars and 3 bullish bars the indicator must look back to the last 6 bars and plot a point figure on the lowest bar to illustrate the Swing low.

I use the heikin-ashi candles.

this is what I am doing:

```
SH = open[5] < close[5] and open[4] < close[4] and open[3] < close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and open[0] > close[0]    
SL = open[5] > close[5] and open[4] > close[4] and open[3] > close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and open[0] < close[0]

plotchar(SH, title='Swing High', char='•', location=location.abovebar, color=color.blue, offset = highestbars(6))    
plotchar(SL, title='Swing Low', char='•', location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, offset = lowestbars(6))
```

For some reason sometimes it does not plot the • on the correct bar. As it shows on the chart below the red or blue point should be where the arrow is pointing. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`plotchar()` is no good for your application because your offset will be dynamic.

Use `label` instead.

```
//@version=4
study("My script", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)

SH = open[5] < close[5] and open[4] < close[4] and open[3] < close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and open[0] > close[0]    
SL = open[5] > close[5] and open[4] > close[4] and open[3] > close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and open[1] < close[1] and open[0] < close[0]

SH_offset = -highestbars(6)
SL_offset = -lowestbars(6)

if (SH)
    label.new(bar_index - SH_offset, high, "SH", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.blue, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.blue)

if (SL)
    label.new(bar_index - SL_offset, low, "SL", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.red, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.red)
```